# Using a spinner to populate RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am loading a list from Firebase's Firestore DB to populate a spinner. That works. I want to populate a RecyclerView upon ItemSelected in the spinner.

I have this code to populate RecyclerView:

```
private void populateRecycler(final String RootCollection, final String UserID) {
    final String UserID = getIntent().getExtras().getString(UserIDKey);
    mQuery = mFirestore
            .collection(RootCollection)
            .whereEqualTo("UID", UserID)
            .orderBy("DateAdded", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    mAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(mQuery, HomeActivity.this);

    mOrdersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

This code works fine if it's placed or called from onCreate. But I want to modify the code later to populate base on String in the spinner later. (probably just to add another .whereEqualto)

When I call `populateRecycler()` from here, it doesn't work (I'm using ButterKnife, fyi):

```
@OnItemSelected(R.id.storespinner)
public void spinnerItemSelected(Spinner spinner, int position) {
    String spinnerValue = mStoreSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected item " + spinnerValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
populateRecycler("test", UserID);
}
```

Or if I call populateRecycler from another onSuccess listener (Firebase Firestore DB call), it also does not work:

```
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    UIDOrg uidOrg = documentSnapshot.toObject(UIDOrg.class);
                    mOrgTextView.setText(uidOrg.getOrg()); 
                    RootCollection = uidOrg.getRootCollection();
                    populateRecycler("test", UserID);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Why does `populateRecycler` only work when called from onCreate?

Edit:
This is how I fill the spinner array.

```
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    UIDOrg uidOrg = documentSnapshot.toObject(UIDOrg.class);
                    mOrgTextView.setText(uidOrg.getOrg());
                    RootCollection = uidOrg.getRootCollection();

                    //Populate Spinner here
                    readData(new FirestoreCallBack() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCallback(List<String> list) {
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            mStoreSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });
                    //End of Spinner
                }
```

And in readData() it's:

```
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                           spinnerArray.add(String.valueOf(document.getId()));
                        }
                        firestoreCallBack.onCallback(spinnerArray);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work'?

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify. Nothing appears on the screen. But no error whatsoever.

Comment: Did you try adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you've changed the data for the recycler view?

Comment: Yes I just did on the `populateRecycler`, added `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but still the same.

Comment: What does this line of code return? `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected item " + spinnerValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: It returns the selected spinner Array's String.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've used your suggested code from the other post to fill the Spinner Array from Firestore FYI. Post edited above to show this.

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: The spinner Array works fine. The issue is now the recycler that appears empty or not called.

I suspect it's an issue with `mAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(mQuery, HomeActivity.this);

    mOrdersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

That it doesn't like to be called from other places except onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I guess after-all it's really a Firestore solution.

I really just needed this line when populateRecycler is called from elsewhere other than onCreate.

```
   mAdapter.setQuery(query);
```

Firestore is already updating the Recycler dynamically, all I needed to do was to update a new query and then .setQuery(query) so that the Recycler view is updated.

Answer (score 0):

firstly check with this method, your `onItemSelected` working properly on not:

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }

         @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

         }
     });
```

if it is working fine then issue may be in your declaration with `ButterKnife`. See my example its working properly.
firstly declare spinner in `Activity` like this:

```
  @InjectView(R.id.spinner)
    Spinner spinner;
```

then in `oncreate` method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("test");
        list.add("test1");
        list.add("test2");
        list.add("test3");
        list.add("test4");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

then outside this method i declare `OnItemSelected` in `activity`

```
   @OnItemSelected(R.id.spinner)
    public void spinnerItemSelected(Spinner spinner, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

try this and check what going wrong with your code.

Comment: Yea my code is almost exactly the same. my Toast..makeText in `public void spinnerItemSelected` works. Only `populateRecycler` doesn't.

Comment: means  toast showing in this method spinnerItemSelected but  populateRecycler not working. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, correct. 

But if I call `populateRecycler` from onCreate, it works.

Comment: i check the same scenario its working fine i think issue is in your this code:   final String UserID = getIntent().getExtras().getString(UserIDKey);
    mQuery = mFirestore
            .collection(RootCollection)
            .whereEqualTo("UID", UserID)
            .orderBy("DateAdded", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

Comment: plzz check you are getting  final String UserID = getIntent().getExtras().getString(UserIDKey);
   this data properly or not , i think in onCreate you are getting properly but outside not

Comment: Yes I am getting that right. I have a `Log.d` to show me `UserID` - it's all showing up fine..

Comment: and also getting list mQuery properly? because you take the same object final String UserID in method as well as parameter of method so may be in mis-configured with this for fetching data

Comment: mQuery is fine because it works from onCreate, no problem.

Even if I remove the Variable UserID, and manually insert a static text in there, it still doesn't work.

Comment: could you show me the method for setting spinner array item with adapter

Comment: your code looking fine. create an activity object like this public static MainActivity mainActivity; and set in oncreate method mainActivity=this; then call your method like this mainActivity.populateRecycler("test", UserID); try this

Answer (score 0):

if you call populateRecycler method on spinner value selection time that used below code i not provide the code in butter kinfe library but provide simple java code and you will convert into butter kinfe code ...

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected item " + spinnerValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            populateRecycler("test", UserID);        
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes this would be the same code as without ButterKnife. I've tried this too, same issue.

Comment: check your spinner is containing string array because i test above code is working.

Comment: Yes, my spinner contains the strings no problem. But when populateRecycler is called from setOnItemSelectedListener - my recyclerview is empty.

But when populateRecycler is called from onCreate, it gets populated.